# Many-to-many relationship on EF core 1.0 code first with model first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I already have the following tables.

```
create table A (Id char(8) primary key, .....)
create table B (Id int primary key, .....)
create table A_B (AId references A(Id), BId references B(Id), primarykey(AId, BId))
```

What's the best way to define the class for these many-to-many relationship?

```
class A { 
    public string Id { get; set; } 
    .... 
    public List<B> Bs { get; set; } or List<A_B> A_Bs?
}
class B {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ....
    public List<A> As { get; set; } or List<A_B> A_Bs?
}
class A_B ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EFCore doesn't support many-to-many without join table yet, so you must use something like:

```
class A {
      List<A_B> A_Bs {get;set;}
    }

    class A_B {
      int AId {get;set;}
      A MyA {get;set;}
      int BId {get;set;}
      B MyB {get;set;}
    }

class B {
    List<A_B> A_Bs {get;set;}
}
```